# How to override a state in riverpod with GoRouter?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-go-router

I need to override the state of a provider for a specific subtree. At defaults it throws `UnimplemedtedError`, I wanted to give it a value for next screens.

My routes are as follow:

```
=> /splash
=> (ShellRoute)
=>   /
=>   /chat
=>   /settings
=> /login
```

On `login` screen when the user logs we navigate to home (`/`) passing the `Person` object in order to make it available for `chat` and `settings`:

```
router.go('/', extra: person);
```

Here's the declaration of the provider:

```
final personProvider = Provider<Person>((ref) {
  throw UnimplementedError();
});
```

I tried scoping in the shell route

```dart
ShellRoute(
  builder: (context, state, child) {
    return ProviderScope(
      overrides: [
        personProvider.overrideWithValue(state.extra as Person),
      ],
      child: child,
    );
  },
  routes: [
    // home route (/)
    // chat route (/chat)
    // settings route (/settings)
  ],
),
```

but it works only for home (`/`) when we come from login.

I feel like I am doing something wrong, any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try override provider to all of Routes under ShellRoute like this:

```
ShellRoute(
  builder: (context, state, child) {
    return ProviderScope(
      overrides: [
        personProvider.overrideWithValue(state.extra as Person),
      ],
      child: child,
    );
  },
  routes: [
 // home route (/)
 GoRoute(
  builder: (context, state, child) {
    return ProviderScope(
      overrides: [
        personProvider.overrideWithValue(state.extra as Person),
      ],
      child: child,
    );
  },

 // chat route (/chat)
 GoRoute(
  builder: (context, state, child) {
    return ProviderScope(
      overrides: [
        personProvider.overrideWithValue(state.extra as Person),
      ],
      child: child,
    );
  },

 // settings route (/settings)
 GoRoute(
  builder: (context, state, child) {
    return ProviderScope(
      overrides: [
        personProvider.overrideWithValue(state.extra as Person),
      ],
      child: child,
    );
  },
  ],
),
```

Comment: That means we need to pass the **Person** object every time we navigate to a new page and **riverpod** will have no use here. We want to pass it only once (after login) and access it everywhere from home.
Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Provider is for one-time value. If your value will change, you should use StateProvider/NotifierProvier.

Comment: The value doesn't change, and even if I use `StateProvider<Person>` instead of `Provider<Person>`, I'll have to either return a default `Person` object or make the value type optional and return null;